# How to escape a comma in json passed as args in a VSCode launcher.json command?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I would like to debug an APP and need to pass a in-line json as arg.
I did the following:

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "app DEV",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": [
                "--dart-define=APP_BACKENDS={[{\"id\":\"default\",\"url\":\"https://localhost\",\"port\": \"8080\"},]}",
            ]
        }
```

but the APP_BACKENDS const value is getting stripped in the first comma. lock the print of it: `{[{"id":"default"`

---

just to be clear. that is the way I'm getting the value I've printed:

```
static const _APP_BACKENDS =
      String.fromEnvironment('APP_BACKENDS', defaultValue: '{}');
```

Comment: Did you try to escape the comma as well?

Comment: try to remove the space after the `port` definition, now the string will be escaped with `"`

Comment: @limido, yes... the editor didn't accept

Comment: @rioV8, no difference removing that space

Comment: in JSON you can't have an array as an object key: `{[]}`

Comment: @Cristiano please let me know if the solution given works out for you, else, I will see for any improvements needed to achieve the solution

Answer (score 5):

After going through a lot of links and reading, finally I found a GitHub issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98471 which solved my similar problem. If you go through the link and read the second last comment it explains the things regarding shell quoting.

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "app DEV",
        "program": "lib/main.dart",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "args": [
            "--dart-define=APP_BACKENDS={[{\"id\":\"default\",\"url\":\"https://localhost\",\"port\": \"8080\"},]}",
        ],
        "argsExpansion": "none"
    }
```

**"argsExpansion": "none"** after adding this to my launch.json file I was able to run the code without adding extra \ or spaces as mentioned in other answers. I tried searching for this configuration in vscode docs but did not find any reference, however it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks so much @Indrajit... an example:
`
        {
            "name": "4 - Create Sql/Server",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/api_logic_server_cli",
            "program": "cli.py",
            "redirectOutput": true,
            "argsExpansion": "none",
            "args": ["create","--project_name=../../servers/SqlServer","--db_url=mssql+pyodbc://sa:posey386!@localhost:1433/NORTHWND?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server&trusted_connection=no"],
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue - trying to pass a json string as a command line arg to a python script. Works fine from shell, but couldn't do the same from launch.json. VS Code was intepreting the commas as multiple arguments and passing multiple `-b` args into my program (4x separate `-b` args in my case).

Answer: add a space " " to the end of the arg value.

I fail to understand why this works, but it does. Note I'm single-slash escaping the double-quotes.

```json
{
    "name": "Test my python code",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "args": [
        "-r=/store/purchase",
        "-b={\"items\":[\"cake\",\"coffee\",\"toilet roll\",\"masks\"]} "
    ],
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
},
```

Comment: Can confirm this works.  Although, for my case of passing in a dictionary with multiple key,value pairs I had to ad a space at the start of the dictionary as well.

Comment: genuis! thanks - wasted so much time searching for a solution to unwanted parsing of args

Answer (score 1):

After reading this documentation: [Launch JSON Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference), specifically
[this reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_args), I got to know that, you need to use `\\\` to achieve what you want. For example. In the documentation only this is given

> JSON array of command-line arguments to pass to the program when it is launched. Example `["arg1", "arg2"]`. If you are escaping characters, you will need to double escape them. For example, `["{\\\"arg1\\\": true}"]` will send `{"arg1": true}` to your application

So, after looking at this, you must pass your JSON to your args in a proper format

```
args: [
  "--dart-define=APP_BACKENDS={[{\\\"id\\\":\\\"default\\\",\\\"url\\\":\\\"https://localhost\\\",\\\"port\\\": \\\"8080\\\"}]}"
]
```

This will do your job!

Comment: where on the docs do you see the possibility to define your own variables this way?

Comment: ```{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Program",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "args": ["${env:USERNAME}"]
}``` @rioV8

Comment: these are not user defined variables.

Comment: I am just interested in knowing about it, if it works @rioV8

Comment: @Alok, unfortunately, no difference. look the print: `I/flutter ( 9981): {[{\id\:\default"`

Comment: It is okay @Cristiano I am working on it, I will update my answer when I am done :)

Comment: Hey @Cristiano I have checked in in my console, it prints fine: ```-I/flutter (24049): {[{"id":"default","url":"https://localhost","port": "8080"}]}```. Used your code only. Just pass the args' value in your default and print it ```static const _APP_BACKENDS =
      String.fromEnvironment('APP_BACKENDS', defaultValue: '{[{\"id\":\"default\",\"url\":\"https://localhost\",\"port\": \"8080\"}]}');```

Comment: If you use single quotes as string separator you don't have to escape `"`

Comment: @rioV8, you can learn about dart-define here: https://itnext.io/flutter-1-17-no-more-flavors-no-more-ios-schemas-command-argument-that-solves-everything-8b145ed4285d

You can't use single quotes with launcher.json.

and I'm aware that I need to use  {"a": [ ... ]}

Comment: @Alok, for now, the only way I was able to pass a json was encoding it as base64 and decoding it before processing it in the main method

Comment: @Cristiano Alok is writing JavaScript in his comment and there the escaping is not needed

Answer (score 0):

For future:

if you launching some program with debugger via shell like `gdb` use notation with single quotes:

```
{
    {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main",
            "args": ["'{\"invalid: 123}'"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": []
        }
```

If you skip single quotes gdb will receive from shell something like this for first and second argument to redirect: `{, "invalid: 123}` which will results in EOF exception, because `"` has no ending. If you use single quotes, gdb will receive: `{"invalid: 123}`, which is proper standalone argument with beginning and end.